# Wordpress Shortcode Loop Through Data And Send Current Looped Record To Other Shortcode In Custom Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin that currently returns a stores inventory from the database.

Right now I am simply outputting the raw text.

What I would like to do is output the data and have other shortcodes render the data.

For example:

```
[store_inventory]
[/store_inventory]
```

The above short code would return the following

```
array([0]=['item_name'='Juice', 'item_number' = '3dsj'], [1]=['item_name'='bread', 'item_number' = 'br3d']);
```

What I would like to do is have the store_inventory shortcode loop through the array instead of returning the raw array. And pass every individual returned value it loops through to another set of shortcodes so I can write the data into its own html.

My idea would look like this

```
[store_inventory] //This shortcode loops through the inventory array returned from the database
<div>
<p>[item_name]</p>//This shortcode returns current item_name being looped
<p>[item_number]</p>//This shortcode returns current item_number being looped
</div>
[/store_inventory]
```

I am just not sure how to handle looping through the array and passing the current data record from the array to the other two shortcodes.

Any help would be appreciated.

I know it would be easy to just spit out the HTML already formatted from the plugin but this would mean no front end editing via wordpress or version control via wordpress.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use nested shortcodes rather than have the [store_inventory] shortcode handle looping through the data and generating the markup?

Comment: That is what is required by the frontend team I am working with. Because we are going to re-use this plugin on multiple sites and require having different html structures and styles. Doing it this way seems like it would give the most flexibility. Is there a more standard way to achieve this without having the loop generate the markup?

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through each item in `store_inventory` and pass the data in `do_shortcode`.

I'm not sure how your `store_inventory` shortcode looks like but see below example:

```
function story_inventory_loop( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      //attributes
    ), $atts ) );
    $output = '<div>';
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post', //your post type
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    );
    $query = new  WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $output .= '<p>'.
                   echo do_shortcode( '[item_name]' . get_the_title() . '[/item_name]' ).
                   '</p>'.
                   '<p>'.
                   echo do_shortcode( '[item_number]' . get_the_excerpt(). '[/item_number]' ).
                   '</p><!--  ends here -->';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('store_inventory', 'story_inventory_loop');
```

`item_name` shortcode:

```
function item_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return $content ;
}
add_shortcode( 'item_name', 'item_name_shortcode' );
```

`item_number` shortcode:

```
function item_number_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return $content ;
}
add_shortcode( 'item_number', 'item_number_shortcode' );
```

Hope this helps.